# .htaccess Redirect causes Internal Server Error

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

.htaccess

```
Redirect /index2.html http://example.com/index.html
```

causes the following error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration 
and was unable to complete your request.
```

I think syntax of `Redirect` in this .htaccess is correct because this .htaccess works on another server.
What is the cause of this error?

Comment: What's in Apache's error log?

Comment: @Shane I can't see error log.

Comment: Then can you ask someone for the error log?  Are you absolutely sure that simply removing that line (but leaving the file in place) gets rid of the error?

Comment: @Shane Thanks. I can't ask someone. When I removed Redirect, error didn't happen. For now, I've decided to use html's `meta refresh` instead of `Redirect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I've found that reliably causes this type of error is when `mod_alias` (aka `alias_module`) isn't loaded for some reason. It's usually loaded by default, but could be disabled by the administrator.

You could check whether that's the case by changing your `.htaccess` to:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Redirect /index2.html http://example.com/index.html
</IfModule>
```

If you don't get the error, then `mod_alias` is not loaded, so the `Redirect` directive is unavailable.

If you still get the error, then it's something else. Realistically, you'd need the error log to see what happened.

Comment: thank you very much! I added `<IfModule alias_module>` and I didn't get error.